# Outlook BUG - "Resend This Message" doesn't work for .EML files

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office-2013

I seem to have come across a bug with outlook.

I have an email in eml format, *message.eml*.

In this certain scenario, I want to resend the email using the outlook action `Resend This Message`

[image: Resend Item Screenshot]

*Note: You cannot do this if the email is a .msg, as the option is greyed out*

You edit the message as you wish and press Send.

**Instantly** you will receive an email from outlook (*system administrator*) saying that the email was undeliverable.

[image]

This "email" has no headers, as it is generated locally by outlook.
This is it's content.

> Your message did not reach some or all of the intended recipients.

```
  Subject:  Testing 
  Sent: 16/06/2015 15:16
```

> The following recipient(s) cannot be reached:

```
  Joshua Stevenson (domain here) on 16/06/2015 15:16
  This message could not be sent.
  Try sending the message again later, or contact your network administrator.
  Error is [0x80070005-00000000-00000000].
```

This only seems to happen with `.eml` files, I have tested this on multiple systems with different versions of outlook / windows.

**It works on Windows 7, Outlook 2007**; it doesn't work on Windows 8.1, outlook 2013

Has anyone ever come across this before, and does it happen to you too?

[**DOWNLOAD SAMPLE.EML FOR TESTING HERE**](http://trac.roundcube.net/raw-attachment/ticket/1486584/example.eml)

Comment: The same thing happens for me using that Example EML. Running windows 8.1 (64bit) & Office 2013 (32bit). Interested to see answer

Comment: I have also opened a support case with Microsoft them selves so if I get an answer from them I will post it here.

Comment: Seems this happens for more than just `.EML` files. I'm able to reproduce this behavior with an Outlook `.MSG` file. (Outlook 2013 on Exchange 2010)

Comment: @JoshStevenson What happens if you first drag the `.eml` file to your **Drafts** folder, then execute the *Resend* function?  This worked for me with a `.msg` file.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work for me @Twisty :( interesting that you get the same error with `.msg` files though. an `eml` is one file containing everything in the text of the file, while an `msg` is simply a ZIP file ( _if you rename one to `.zip` you can extract it with 7Zip_ ) I thought that had something to do with it, obviously not!

Comment: @JoshStevenson Though you cannot repro with a `.MSG` file I think the take-away is that this behavior may not be specifically related to `.eml` files. FWIW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It indeed doesn't work with Outlook 2013... **if your EMLs contain From: header** (doesn't matter what address is).

To workaround this, just delete **From:** header from your EML files (using any text editor like Notepad, remove the line that starts with "From: "). When resending them, you'll get additional warning but it will work!

Another workaround is to select the same account in From field on Outlook message's window (yes, just select the same account you're already seeing on message).

Comment: Just open EML in any text editor (say, Notepad) and delete the line that begins with "From: ", it has to be near the beginning of the file.

Comment: Then how will the recipient know who sent the email...?

Comment: They will know. Outlook will fill the sender to your own address automatically.

Comment: Yes, error 0x80070005 means that the issue is related to permissions - so definitely it is a problem with FROM field. This functionality you want to use is probably blocked by design as unsecure, so it is not a bug.